# Move camera layer position ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am setting overlay over camera using

[_imagePickerController setCameraOverlay:_overlayView];

and after after this i was croping image of visible area of overlayView.

This was working fine in all sizes with ios 6.

but after ios 7 in market it causing me problem .. have a look at real problem

This is Camera app in ios 7 iphone 5, where camera is starting from bottom of top black bar
[image]

Now this is what i am getting when i am setting camera controls no in my app ,here camera is starting from above . But i want to start camera like some 20 pixels down.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes i did solve this ,please have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As this i am facing this problem in ios 7 and iphone 5 so i made one condition and translate camera and after this camera starts from 10 pixel down .

```
_imagePickerCtrl.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>=7.0 && self.view.frame.size.height>481) {

            CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0,10.0);
            _imagePickerCtrl.cameraViewTransform = translate;

        }
```